# Is it possible for a Super class to have sub class objects? c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So, lets say I have a superclass named Lights. I then have two subsclasses that extend Lights, Light_Omni and Light_Spot. Is it possible in Lights to have Light_Omni and Light_Spot objects?

I tried forward declaration of the sub-classes in Lights.h, as I read somewhere, for not the same case as mine, it's similiar though. But I'm either doing it wrong, or it just won't work.

```
class LG_Light_Spot;
class LG_Light_Omni;

class LG_Lights
{
   LG_Light_Spot obj1;
   LG_Light_Omni obj2;
};

class LG_Light_Spot :
    public LG_Lights
{};

class LG_Light_Omni :
    public LG_Lights
{};
```

Right now I'm getting "unresolved externals" when i try to build the project.
Hope it's not a stupid question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code fragments you've posted (apart from using [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783), but that's unlikely to cause the problem). Which externals are unresolved? Can you post a minimal, compilable test case to demonstrate?

Comment: It is possible to have a class member based on a forward declaration so long as the full declaration is included in every compilation unit *however* this is strictly a non-standard visual C++ extension and you probably should not be doing it, use forward declarations and pointers instead.

Comment: @sjdowling: How do you expect that to work when part of the definition of the type of the member is the type of the enclosing object? You can't have `struct A { A obj; };` either, for just the same reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right that it's not going to work in this instance, I was making a more general point and that's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The definitions would be recursive; what would the size of an `LG_Lights` be?

You can't have `struct A { A obj; };` either, for just the same reason.

Comment: But you *CAN* have pointers to captive instances of derived classes.

Comment: Regarding that issue, that is what I was thinking, I was going to use pointers for the objects. I should have wrote the LG_Lights code completely. The code was edited, I guess it was too long to post anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on LRiO's answer, remember that every instance of a derived class contains a base subobject which is an instance of the base class (or subobjects/classes, in case there are multiple).

So you are asking for `LG_Lights` to contain an `LG_Light_Spot` as a member subobject which contains an `LG_Lights` as a base subobject which contains an `LG_Light_Spot` as a member subobject... and it's turtles all the way down.

At some point you need to make this containment optional, for which purpose a `std::unique_ptr<DerivedClass>` will work fine.

Or else you need to rethink your inheritance.  It makes sense that a spotlight is-a light.  But you say that a spotlight is-a light**s**, plural.  Not in the real world, and not in the C++ type system.

Comment: Thank you too, I understood it. I'll re-think my code.